# Notice: Use of undefined constant JSON_HEX_TAG - assumed 'JSON_HEX_TAG'

Tags: php, json

Good day.

```
$arr = array(1, "Hello");
json_encode($arr, JSON_HEX_TAG | JSON_HEX_APOS | JSON_HEX_QUOT | JSON_HEX_AMP);
```

when i use code i get notice:

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant JSON_HEX_TAG - assumed 'JSON_HEX_TAG' in ....

Notice: Use of undefined constant JSON_HEX_APOS - assumed 'JSON_HEX_APOS' in ....

Notice: Use of undefined constant JSON_HEX_QUOT - assumed 'JSON_HEX_QUOT' in ....

Notice: Use of undefined constant JSON_HEX_AMP - assumed 'JSON_HEX_AMP' in ....

Warning: json_encode() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given in ....
```

Anyone know why i get it notice?

Comment: It looks like your running an older version of PHP. [Those constants were added from php 5.3](http://php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php)

Comment: PHP 5.3.0 is required

Comment: what do if on hosting php 5.2.17?

Comment: You'll need to consider which of those functions you _really_ need, and create a PHP function that does what you need. There's no point in using `define()` to create the constants - the JSON encoder doesn't have the functionality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using a version of PHP earlier than 5.3. Those constants are only available in PHP 5.3+